# Citing an online news article using BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, online

I want to cite an online news article, i.e. one that didn't also appear as a printed version, using BibLaTex with the authoryear style. Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,bibtotocnumbered,abstract=on]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,doi=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Export-Test.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    urlseen = {abgerufen am},
}

\begin{document}
Test \autocite{Darroch.2017}.

\end{document}
```

with the corresponding entry in the `.bib` file:

```
@Online{Darroch.2017,
 author = {Darroch, Gordon},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Netherlands 'will pay the price' for blocking Turkish visit – Erdoğan },
 journal = {The Guardian},
 url = {https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/mar/12/netherlands-will-pay-the-price-for-blocking-turkish-visit-erdogan},
 urldate = {2017-03-12}
}
```

The output looks like this:

Darroch, Gordon (2017). *Netherlands 'will pay the price' for blocking Turkish visit – Erdoğan* URL: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/mar/12/netherlands-will-pay-the-price-for-blocking-turkish-visit-erdogan (abgerufen am 12.03.2017)

I've tried multiple things instead of `journal`, but the name of the news website just doesn't want to appear. In the end, it should look like this:

Darroch, Gordon (2017). Netherlands 'will pay the price' for blocking Turkish visit – Erdoğan In: *The Guardian*. URL: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/mar/12/netherlands-will-pay-the-price-for-blocking-turkish-visit-erdogan (abgerufen am 12.03.2017)

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do any of the following fields work? {subtitle, titleaddon, language, version, note, organization, date, month, year, addendum, pubstate, urldate}.  Regardless, @article might be more appropriate for a news article.

Comment: Use `@article` and it will work much better. There is almost certainly a print equivalent, but that doesn't really matter if it is not the version you have access to. You should, however, definitely specify `date` rather than just `year` for a newspaper article.

Comment: If you want the `journal`/`journaltitle` to appear, you should use `@article`. It seems in no way inappropriate to use that entry type.

Comment: @Mass I have added a CW answer, but if you would rather like to answer yourself I will vote to delete the CW answer.

Answer (score 27):

You will want to use the `@article` entry type.

```
@article{Darroch.2017,
 author  = {Darroch, Gordon},
 date    = {2017-03-12},
 title   = {Netherlands 'will pay the price' for blocking Turkish visit – Erdoğan},
 journal = {The Guardian},
 url     = {https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/mar/12/netherlands-will-pay-the-price-for-blocking-turkish-visit-erdogan},
 urldate = {2017-03-12}
}
```

Since this is arguably an article that appeared in the online version of a newspaper, you should be fine using `@article`.

As cfr noted in the comments, it is a good idea to specify the publishing date (with newer versions you can even give the time as well `date    = {2017-03-12T19:57:00}`).

Comment: Yes, I just checked again and I indeed used a different style. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using EndNote so had to configure the export fields for a Newspaper Article as shown below. Using biblatex this seems to put everything in the right order.

```
@article{|Label,|
|   `author = `{Reporter},
|   `title = `{Title},
|   `year = `{Year},
|   `journal = `{Newspaper},
|   `note = `{Available at: \url{URL} (Accessed: {Access Date})},
|   `month = `{Issue Date},
|   `type = `{Reference Type}
```

So the resulting bib entry is

```
@article{Allen2018,
   author = {Allen, Kate},
   title = {African Development Bank turns to hedge fund to offset risk},
   year = {2018},
   journal = {Financial Times},
   note = {Available at: \url{https://www.ft.com/content/6eba4d10-ba43-11e8-94b2-17176fbf93f5} (Accessed: {April 24th, 2023})},
   month = {18 Sep},
   type = {Newspaper Article}
}
```